# "Transposition" of functors?

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

Recently I had to write the following function:

```
mToL :: Maybe [a] -> [Maybe a]
mToL Nothing = []
mToL (Just xs) = map Just xs
```

This begged the question whether it is possible to generalize the above to:

```
transposeF :: (Functor f, Functor g) => f (g a) -> g (f a)
```

I guess it only works if there is a way to "collapse" `f (g a)` into `f a`, or is there any other way?

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't necessarily a symmetric operation—moving `f (g a) -> g (f a)` might be possible without having `g (f a) -> f (g a)`.

Comment: The class you want is probably [Distributive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, there is a type class that would support this. It's not included in the standard type class but "representable functors" have this capability.

A representative functor is a functor `F` with two things

1. a type `A`
2. An isomorphism between `F` and `(->) A`

We could represent this as

```
 type family ReprObj (f :: * -> *):: *

 class Functor f => Repr f where
   toHom   :: f a -> (ReprObj f -> a)
   fromHom :: (ReprObj f -> a) -> f a
```

where `toHom . fromHom = fromHom . toHom = id`. An example of a representable functor,

```
 newtype Pair a = Pair (a, a) deriving Functor
 type instance ReprObj Pair = Bool

 instance Repr Pair where
   toHom (Pair (a, b)) True  = a
   toHom (Pair (a, b)) False = b
   fromHom f = Pair (f True, f False)
```

Now using this we can derive

```
swap :: (Functor f, Functor g, Repr f, Repr g) => f (g a) -> g (f a)
swap g = fromHom $ \obj -> fmap ($ obj) hom
   where hom = fmap toHom g
```

In fact, we can also get a free applicative and monad instance out of representable functors. I detailed how you could do this in a [blog post](http://jozefg.bitbucket.org/posts/2013-10-21-representable-functors.html).

Comment: The link to your blog post is broken. Here's a link from the wayback machine that works. http://web.archive.org/web/20160507044828/http://jozefg.bitbucket.org/posts/2013-10-21-representable-functors.html

Answer (score 13):

[The `Traversable` typeclass](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html) provides the `sequence` and `sequenceA` operations, which provide the most general solutions to your problem, but they require different constraints:

```
sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)

sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

Answer (score 10):

This is not possible in general, no. Set `f` to `Const b` and `g` to `Identity`.

```
newtype Const b a = Const { getConst :: b }
newtype Identity a = Identity { runIdentity :: a }
```

These are both obviously functors with their normal instances. `transposeF` can't work because `Const b` doesn't supply any `a`s with which to wrap with Identity. So you can't write the transposition function.

On the other hand, this is nice for a whole lot of Functor pairings. The categorical notion is that of the [adjoint functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors) and once you see them, you'll start seeing them everywhere. They're a very powerful notion in their own right.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do so using functors simply because there's no generic way to unwrap a functor value:

```
Prelude> :info Functor
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  (GHC.Base.<$) :: a -> f b -> f a
    -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
instance Functor Maybe -- Defined in `Data.Maybe'
instance Functor (Either a) -- Defined in `Data.Either'
instance Functor [] -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
instance Functor IO -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
instance Functor ((->) r) -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
instance Functor ((,) a) -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
```

Instead you could create your own typeclass to provide a generic `transpose` function as follows:

```
import Control.Applicative

class Applicative f => Transposable t where
    unwrap :: t a -> a
    transpose :: s (t a) -> t (s a)
    transpose = fmap pure . unwrap
```

The reason we make `Applicative` a superclass of `Transposable` is so that we can use its `pure` method. All instances of `Applicative` are also instances of `Functor`.